# How to do a Cartesian product for words in a list using Python

Tags: python, cartesian-product

It turned out I was looking for combinations and not the Cartesian product.

---

I need to do a Cartesian product of several words (all of them inside a list).

My input looks something like this:

```
[[id, [word1,word2,word3]],[id2,[word4,word5,word6]]]
```

The product needs to be made on the words in the first index inside each list of lists. Meaning - on word1, words2, and word3 between themselves, on word4, words5, and word6 between themselves and so on.

My code so far:

```
for row in x:
    row[1] = list(itertools.product(*row[1])
```

The problem is that the script does the product on each of the **letters** and not on each one of the words.

I get something like: `(w,w,w), (w,o,r), (w,o,d)`, etc.

The expected output is: `(word1,word2), (word1,word3), (word2,word3)`. The same thing for the other parts..

Comment: What is the expected output, btw?

Comment: Edited and added the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` takes several iterables as input. The Cartesian product is taken between the iterables given. E.g. `itertools.product([1, 2], [3, 4])` gives `[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]`.

Having said that, what you actually meant to call was `itertools.combinations`

```
for row in x:
    row[1] = list(itertools.combinations(row[1], 2))
```

Comment: it gives me also combinations I don't want such as (word1,word1,word1),(word1,word1,word2).

Comment: @Shachar183, fixed it. I already thought you'd say that but were not sure

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `[list(itertools.product(row[1], repeat=len(row[1]))) for row in x]`. You do not need to use the `*` operator to unpack `row[1]`, as [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) takes whole iterables as arguments. To calculate the Cartesian Product of each row "between themselves", use the repeat paramater.

Answer (score 0):

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/python
  2 # vim: noet sw=4 ts=4
  3 
  4 d = [["id", ["word1","word2","word3"]],["id2"["word4","word5","word6"]]]
  5 inner = d[0][1]
  6 outer = d[1][1]
  7 for o in outer:
  8     for i in inner:
  9         print '{0}x{1}'.format( i, o )

word1xword4
word2xword4
word3xword4
word1xword5
word2xword5
word3xword5
word1xword6
word2xword6
word3xword6
```

Comment: Can you improve formatting and add a little bit of explaination what you're doing?